# Unit Test - Moq - The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncQueryProvider

Tags: unit-testing, moq, xunit, asp.net-core-identity, ef-core-2.2

I'm new to unit test and Moq. I have a repository class to retrieve users. Here is the repository class code:

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
    {
        private readonly UserManager<UserEntity> _userManager;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public UserRepository(
            UserManager<UserEntity> userManager,
            IMapper mapper)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetUsersAsync(
            PagingOptions pagingOptions)
        {
            IQueryable<UserEntity> query = _userManager.Users;
            //    query = searchOptions.Apply(query);
            //    query = sortOptions.Apply(query);

            var size = await query.CountAsync();

            var items = await query
                .Skip(pagingOptions.Offset.Value)
                .Take(pagingOptions.Limit.Value)
                .ProjectTo<User>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                .ToArrayAsync();

            return items;
        }
}
```

This works fine when I run the application normally as shown in the below image.

[image: working code]

But When I run the same code using x-unit unit test project, I get the below error when executing `var size = await query.CountAsync();`:

> The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement
>   IAsyncQueryProvider. Only providers that implement IAsyncQueryProvider
>   can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.

Here is my unit test code:

```
public class UserRepositoryTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public async void GetUsers_AtleastOne_ReturnOneOrMore()
        {
            // Arrange
            var connectionStringBuilder =
                new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder { DataSource = ":memory:" };
            var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ToString());

            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<GallaContext>()
                .UseSqlite(connection)
                .Options;

            var mockHttpContextAccessor = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            var mockUserManager = new Mock<UserManager<UserEntity>>(new Mock<IUserStore<UserEntity>>().Object,
                    new Mock<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Object,
                    new Mock<IPasswordHasher<UserEntity>>().Object,
                    new IUserValidator<UserEntity>[0],
                    new IPasswordValidator<UserEntity>[0],
                    new Mock<ILookupNormalizer>().Object,
                    new Mock<IdentityErrorDescriber>().Object,
                    new Mock<IServiceProvider>().Object,
                    new Mock<ILogger<UserManager<UserEntity>>>().Object);
            var autoMapper = new MapperConfiguration(mc => mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile())).CreateMapper();

            var pagingOptions = new PagingOptions
            {
                Limit = 25,
                Offset = 0
            };

            using (var context = new GallaContext(options, mockHttpContextAccessor.Object))
            {
                context.Database.OpenConnection();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                var userRepository = new UserRepository(mockUserManager.Object, autoMapper);

                // Act
                var users = await userRepository.GetUsersAsync(pagingOptions);

                // Assert
                users.Should().HaveCountGreaterOrEqualTo(1);
            }
        }
    }
```

<s>Am I mocking the `UserManager` wrongly? Also my context class has data to be added in database in `OnModelCreating` method. So the context has data when `context.Database.EnsureCreated();` is called in unit test. Here is the screenshot of the error image while running unit test</s>

[image: unit test exception]

Thanks,

Abdul

Comment: Did you consider to use In-Memory provider for DbContext? Then you don't need to mock user manager

Comment: You mean `options.UseInMemoryDatabase("dbname")`? But with this I'm not able to verify Foreign Key Violation, Unique Constraints. That's why I moved to `Sqlite`

Comment: Then use Sqlite, my point still stands - don't mock user manager then.

Comment: Then without mocking how can I pass user manager instance?

Comment: Why you are creating sqlite DbContext if you don't use it in test?

Comment: I'm using `Sqlite` in my tests. Notice that I'm passing `options` in the `GallaContext` instance.

Comment: Yes, but you not passing created context anywhere...

Comment: But `context.Database.OpenConnection();context.Database.EnsureCreated();` is.required to seed master user data. At least that needs to be returned right? Or how to handle this Please assist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196092/discussion-between-abdul-rahman-and-fabio).

Comment: Check not accepted answer from the duplicated question [https://stackoverflow.com/a/49174248/1565525](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49174248/1565525) and last comment on the answer if you want to use DbContext in tests.

Comment: @Fabio After analyzing this yesterday, I found where I went wrong and what the actual issue is. The issue is not with the `UserManager`. The issue is with EFCore `Async` operations. Now how to add my answer? I'm not able to find a option to add the correct answer. Please assist

Comment: This question can be marked as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/51023223/10851213.
I resolved this by following the answer in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/52800602/10851213